# What does this kind of header mean in a .h file?

Tags: objective-c

I recently came across this formatting for a `.h header file`. Can someone explain to me why this is done this way and what it means? In particular, I am confused about what is in the first set of braces/the repetition? How does this differ from if I were to delete the braces and everything between them?

```
@interface ACustomView : UIView
{
    float chartWidth, chartHeight;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float chartWidth, chartHeight;
@end
```

Comment: properties can be accessed from other classes too. Remaining cant be accesses by other classes

Comment: best explained in here : https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/should-i-use-a-property-or-an-instance-variable/

Comment: This looks like old Objective-C. The compiler didn't autosynthesize instance variables and they had to be declared in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

> How does this differ from if I were to delete the braces and everything between them?

A `@property`, of itself, is just a *method* declaration (or, in your case, two method declarations, a getter and a setter). Typically, you want those methods to be backed by actual instance variable which the getter and setter will get and set. That is what is declared in the curly braces.

Deleting the instance variable declarations in your code doesn't change very much, however, because the compiler will use your `@property` declaration to *autosynthesize* instance variables for you. In other words, you typically need instance variables backing a `@property`, but you don't need to declare them *explicitly*.

In your particular code, however, you have not shown enough information to reveal what's really going on. A lot depends on what you do (or don't do) in the corresponding *.m* file. If you say `@synthesize` for this `@property`, what is synthesized will be these instance variables, `chartWidth` and `chartHeight`. But if you don't say `@synthesize`, you'll get autosynthesis of instance variables `_chartWidth` and `_chartHeight`, and so now, if you also declare `chartWidth` and `chartHeight` instance variables explicitly, you'll have something of a mess on your hands.

Comment: And see the full discussion of this topic in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_property_accessor_synthesis